# How can I save links to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, sharing, bookmarks

Is there a way to save and share webpage links? For example, http://www.example.com.

How can I save that webpage link to a folder and be able to share that link with others?

Comment: I imagine you would need to add these links to a document and share the document?

Comment: Does it have to be Google Docs? There are other bookmark-sharing services out there.

Comment: I suggest to you to use .url files, the scheme is very simple:

https://fileinfo.com/extension/url

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to have a "folder of links" in Drive.

What you can do is create a document and put the links in there. This document can be easily shared with others.

But, as @Krampus mentions, there are plenty of bookmark-sharing services available. Google even has its own one: [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/).
Another one I used before is [Delicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_(website)). Wikipedia has a page on [social bookmarking websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_bookmarking_websites).

Comment: Del.icio.us [passed away](https://mashable.com/article/rip-delicious-bookmarking-site) in 2017. Google Bookmarks is [going the same route](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/07/21/google-is-shutting-down-google-bookmarks-here-are-alternatives/) in September 2021.

Answer (score 4):

I make a new Google Doc and I paste my url on the page as a hyperlink and name it.  Make sure when you use this that your mode for the Google Doc is in viewing mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in an environment where everyone you are sharing with has a Windows PC, you can create a .url file that will act as a link. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any cross-platform equivalent if you are in a cross-platform environment - though .url files may be recognized by some other platforms.

There are many ways to create it:

1. Open Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer, add it to your favorites bar, then drag and drop the favorite on the bar to a folder in Windows, it will create the .url file
2. Open up a text editor, and enter the following:

   [InternetShortcut]

   URL=https://www.myaddress.com/thisfile.ext

   (NOTE that it is only two lines of text, StackExchange is forcing the extra spacing)

   Replace the address after the = with the location you want to link to.
   Save with extension .url
3. Right click in a folder in Windows Explorer, select "New" then
   select "shortcut" and paste the address in the box under "Type the
   location of the item"

Once you have the .url file, you can either upload it to your Google Drive folder or, if you're using the Google Drive App for Windows, you can navigate to it like any other Windows folder and either move it there or create it there to begin with.

To use/share the link:

Users that are using the Google Drive App for Windows can navigate to it in Windows Explorer and double click on it like any other link in Windows and it will bring you to it.

Users not using the App can go to Google Drive in their browser and Google will say "No Preview Available" but under "Try one of the aps below to open or edit this item" you can select "Internet Browser" and it will open it in your browser.

I don't think there's a "perfect" answer to this, but unlike the other answers, this is done at a folder level on Google Drive, doesn't require opening a separate document, and doesn't require installing any 3rd party apps to your Google Drive, which I think may meet the OPs intent.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.  I made a suggested edit and rolled it back simply for you to see my thinking.  Use anything that is helpful or not. I think your answer is valuable.

Comment: FWIW I am using MacOS 14 “Sonoma” and it appears to support `.url` files just fine.

Comment: @AviFlax that's great to know that MacOS also handles `.url` files. I didn't have a MAC to test it on, so I could only be sure it worked in Windows. When I get a chance I'm going to make an update to my answer based on the comments. I just haven't had the time lately.

Answer (score 2):

You can save links with the free Chrome extension `Save to Google Drive`. You can find it at the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne/details).

If you installed the extension it will look like that:

[image: Save to Google Drive]

Comment: That's not working the way you think it should. If you right-click a link and choose "Save to Google Drive", if it's just a simple link you'll be prompted to go to the page and use the "Save to Google Drive" button by the address bar. That context menu option is for saving documents and such. It's a useful extension, but not for this.

Comment: The behavior is strange. I can successfully save some links but in Google Drive they seem messed up.

Answer (score 2):

## Add a .webloc bookmark file

In browser window #1, open the page that you want to create a link for.
In browser window #2, open the Google Drive folder that you want to put it in.

Drag the favicon to the left of the URL in window #1 into the folder space in window #2. It should create a `.webloc` file. If you download this file and open it, it will take you to the linked webpage.

The downside of this method is that you cannot open the link directly from within Google Drive. You'll need to sync it to your computer or download it in order to open it.

Comment: Another downside of this method is that it is specific to macOS. Windows uses `.url` files, and Linux uses a variety of methods, including [`.desktop` files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359492/create-a-shortcut-for-url/)

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  When I drag the favicon into the Drive folder, the mouse cursor shows as a little "prohibited" symbol ( / ) (circle with diagonal slash through it)